# How to edit Mysql innodb_autoinc_lock_mode value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi how can i edit innodb_autoinc_lock_mode in phpMyAdmin i find the value inside server variable and setting inside my phpMyAdmin settings but it is a read only file how can i fix this.After some google searches online i discovered that it can be found in my server configuration file but i have no idea how to locate that am using phpMyAdmin version 4.9.5

Answer (score 0):

Certain MySQL configuration options are set at startup; those are obviously not able to be changed by phpMyAdmin because phpMyAdmin connects after the service has started. `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` is one of those (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode).

To change this, or any other parameter that is set at startup, you have to either modify your MySQL configuration file or pass additional flags to your MySQL startup script.

Comment: ok my website is hosted on hostinger any idea how to locate the sql configuration script because the only file i am able to access is the public_html folder

Comment: If your host manages MySQL for you, then you almost certainly don't have the ability to change their configuration. If your host provides you with a bare metal or virtual machine and you manage all the software on it, then you can probably modify it. What operating system is your host running? The configuration certainly isn't in the `public_html` folder, so if that is truly all you have access to, then it sounds like they are managing the server for you and you won't be able to change it yourself.

Comment: You should ask your hosting provider for assistance, as the specific answer to that is dependent on their configuration and what level service you have.